# Fetching the record one by one dynamically Oracle

Tags: oracle, procedure

I am creating a dynamic procedure which could accept 2 table names.Fetch the records from one table and after certain record (let's say 100 records) i have to issue the commit command.
Both tabName  and temp_tabName are always be identical.Since I have billions of records in first table i am doing the commit after every 10000 records in order to get rid of undo table space problem.

Till now what i did is :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProdecure (
       tabName        IN USER_TABLES.table_name%TYPE,
       temp_tabName   IN USER_TABLES.table_name%TYPE
    )
    IS
       v_sql         VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select * from ' || tabName;
       TEMP_CURSOR   SYS_REFCURSOR;
       COUNT         NUMBER (6) := 0;
    BEGIN
       OPEN TEMP_CURSOR FOR v_sql;

       LOOP
          FETCH TEMP_CURSOR INTO   V_ROW;

        --=================================================================================

         /*
          * I need the code here to fetch the 100 record from TEMP_CURSOR into a Variable
          * and insert into the second table. or one record increment the count and if 
          * count>= 100 commit
          *What would be the data type of V_ROW. How to fetch the data from V_ROW and complete the insert into command.
          */

        --================================================================================
          EXIT WHEN TEMP_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
       END LOOP;

       CLOSE TEMP_CURSOR;
    END MyProdecure;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is exactly what you want, but you can make an if to get the {temp_cursor%rowcount = 100} . That will get you the moment when you get to the 100th row read.

Comment: Why 1 at a time?  Why can't you process the entire set at once? Are you doing additional processing on each of the 100 records? It Just seems inefficient to do this in a loop unless you have additional constraints.

Comment: is this a homework question? In general, committing in batches is not good practice.

Comment: No actually i need to know how to fetch a single  (or 100 record at a time if possible) record/ROW from TEMP_CURSOR  and do some operation like insertion in different table.

Comment: @Boneist No it is not a homework question. I don't have much exposure of PL/Sql.

Comment: @xQbert that would be great.Could you please help me with the Sample code.

Comment: @mcapatna why do you need to commit every 100 rows, out of curiosity? I'd prefer to do the work in one fell swoop, e.g. `execute immediate 'insert into '||table1||' select * from '||table2;`, bearing in mind that a) you ought to know the columns being inserted from/to in your tables and specify them exactly (e.g. `insert into some_table (col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ...from some_other_table;`) and b) the above dynamic statement is prone to sql_injection unless you sanitise the input parameters, which you can do with [dbms_assert](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2).

Comment: @Boneist yes both the tables would always be identical in column name and datatype.In fact second one is same as first one but with out record.Only problem with the approach you have given is table first have billions of record and it is giving tablespace error while inserting. So we are firing the commit after every 10000 record.

Comment: Are you partitioning the data into separate tables? if so: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9524727800346679268 may help.  my approach would have been the same as Boneist's for the insert until I found out BILLIONS of rows are involved.

Comment: @mcapatna is it not possible to get the UNDO tablespace increased to a more suitable size? That's the best solution in this case, assuming this code is to be in production.

Comment: Perhaps it would helpful to explain logically what you are trying to achieve, rather than describe your implementation...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define `V_ROW` in such a way as to make your PL/SQL block work correctly for an input table whose name and structure is not known until runtime.

To make your approach work, you would need to use `DBMS_SQL`.

Have you considered a variation of the following, to bypass the vast majority of the UNDO generation?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure (
       tabName        IN USER_TABLES.table_name%TYPE,
       temp_tabName   IN USER_TABLES.table_name%TYPE
    )
    IS
    l_log_io NUMBER;
    C_BLOCK_SIZE NUMBER := 8192;  -- assuming 8192 byte block size  
    l_undo_bytes NUMBER;  
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO ' || temp_tabName ||
     ' SELECT * FROM ' || tabName;

  select t.log_io, t.used_ublk*C_BLOCK_SIZE undo_bytes 
  into l_log_io, l_undo_bytes
  from v$transaction t 
  where t.addr = ( SELECT s.taddr FROM v$session s WHERE s.sid = USERENV('SID'));

  dbms_output.put_line('Undo bytes used: ' || l_undo_bytes);
END;
```

`INSERT /*+ APPEND */` comes with a number of caveats that you should look into before using it, but it could be a much simpler way of accomplishing your goal.